# mvc using IHttpHandler, getting 500 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following handler (.ashx) file in the root of my application:

```
    public class KeepSessionAlive : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Session["KeepSessionAlive"] = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I've added the below to my RouteConfig.cs:

```
            routes.IgnoreRoute("KeepSessionAlive.ashx");
```

I've also added the below to my web.config:
under system.web -> httphandlers:

```
<add verb="*" path="/KeepSessionAlive.ashx" type="MyWeb.KeepSessionAlive" validate="false" />
```

and under system.webserver -> handlers

```
<add name="KeepSessionAlive" path="/*.ashx" verb="*" type="MyWeb.KeepSessionAlive" />
```

The problem I keep running into is the site keeps looking for the handler in the same folder the page is in, rather than the root.  For example, if I hit the homepage, in Fiddler I see this:

```
GET /MySite/KeepSessionAlive.ashx?c=678962070347 HTTP/1.1
```

which returns a 200 and works.  However if I go to a subfolder page, like /MySite/Payment/Edit I see this when I leave that Edit page in Fiddler:

```
GET /EAOTracking/Payment/EditAM/KeepSessionAlive.ashx?c=776502292135 HTTP/1.1
```

this then returns a 500 error, which states:
System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in 'MyWeb.Controllers.PaymentController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

My Edit Action definition looks like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

I'm not sure why the Handler isn't always found on the root folder, as it works if I in the root folder of the site.

Comment: Using handlers is not an `mvc-way`, you should use global filters for such functionality

Comment: What causes requests from the browser to the ashx handler? Do you reference the handler in your views somehow?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I didn't add anything into the views, it just gets called as it's a handler, any request it gets called.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin this was actually something we brought in from a webforms project.  we are still new to mvc, it was working there and seems to be working for the most part here, except for when we go into subfolders

Comment: Can you try changing the path to this: `path="~/KeepSessionAlive.ashx" ?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin just tried, same error.

Comment: If you see it in Fiddler it means the client (browser) makes an **explicit** request for some reason. Handlers aren't called on their own, not to mention only a single handler is executed upon a single request. It is not it is called because you registered it.

Comment: @WiktorZychla yup, you were right, I looked around and saw a call from a .js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to call page at aboslute url - use absolute url like

```
 "/KeepSessionAlive.ashx"
```

Using relative url ("KeepSessionAlive.ashx") on a page (I assume you use JavaScript to ping the handler) will combine it with page's base url.

Comment: Turns out there was a reference to it in a .js file, had to adjust that to pick up from the root.