# Getting HTTP 500 error after using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm a new user of ASP .Net and am following an online course to learn it. The course uses Visual Studio 2015 or 2013 and I am using Visual Studio 2017 to code. The course was introducing MVC and routing and put in the following segments of code in the Startup.cs file:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.UseMvc(config =>
            {
                config.MapRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",

                   defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
                   );
            });
            app.UseStaticFiles();

        }
```

I did look up some online resources and the code seems right. But I still get a HTTP 500 error when I run the program.

Also, the course seems to be using MVC 6 but my version is 1.1.2, even though I assume mine is more recent. I don't seem to understand why is this so.

I apologise in advance if this seems like a duplicate. When I did a search, the closest match I got was:
[mvc using IHttpHandler, getting 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782444/mvc-using-ihttphandler-getting-500-error)

which isn't what I'm  trying to ask.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an `AppController`?

Comment: You should take a look at the tutorials from Microsoft themselves on the asp.net core site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/

Comment: @Amy, Yes I do have an AppController

Comment: @Nkosi, I did, the code seems right, but I still get a 500 error